# Android native audio recorder sample rate

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

I'm looking at native-audio example. 
What is the default sample rate?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

**native-audio-jni.c**

```
    // configure audio source
    SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bufq = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
    SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
        SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
    SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_bufq, &format_pcm};
```

The constants are defined in `/ARCHITECTURE/usr/include/SLES/OpenSLES.h`

```
#define SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8          ((SLuint32) 8000000)
```

So the sample rate should be 8kHz.

Comment: But note the comment above: /** These macros specify the commonly used sampling rates (in milliHertz) supported by most audio I/O devices. */  I think the answer is that there isn't a default sampling rate.